# How to register bean at run-time in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wsdl

I've tried different ways of registering the bean at runtime, it is being registered but wsdl page is not working. How can I register this bean at the run-time?

```
@Bean(name = "test")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema commonSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("testPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/BillingWebService");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(commonSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the whole class definition OR Check is the class annotated with @Configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this class being annotated with @Configuration? Also when the application starts can you see any errors related to this bean not being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Either define the beans in your `main class` (i.e.   class containing @SpringBootApplication) or add @ `Configuration` to the class in which you are defining the beans
 Eg -

```
@Configuration 
public class HelloWorldConfig { 

@Bean 
public HelloWorld helloWorld(){
   return new HelloWorld(); 
} 
}
```

or

```
@SpringBootApplication 
public class MyApplication { 
     @Bean    
      public String AppName(){ 
          return "SpringApp"; 
     } 
     public static void main(String[] args) {       
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args); 
    }
}
```